# MySqlDataAdapter doesn't clear DataTable when select query returns no rows?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I don't understand How the `MySQL Data Adapter Fill` method really works. Everything was working fine until i try to fill a data table from and empty MySQL table. The Data Table doesn't get cleared to reflect the empty MySQL Table Why?

In my database I have multiple tables with the exact same schema but one table is empty and the other has rows.

Scenario 1:

lets say I run the fill method on an empty data Table and the select command on a MySQL table with rows The data table is filled accordingly.

scenario 2

lets say I run the Fill method on same data table (which has rows now) but I run the select command on a different MySQL table which also has rows but the same exact schema. The Data Table gets cleared and filled to reflect this new MySQL Table.

scenario 3:

lets say I run the Fill method on same data table (which has rows now) but I run the select command on a different MySQL table with no rows but same exact schema. The Data Table Doesn't get cleared to reflect the empty MySQL Table Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataAdapter  fill the datatable from the database.

```
    DataAdapter da = new DataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.fill(dt);
```

In case if your dataAdapter is null it would not fill the dataTable. hence your dataTable  doesn't change.

however you can use `dt.Clear()` method to clear the datatable.

Comment: I am dealing with data tables not data sets

Comment: same goes for datatable.

Comment: ok I don't understand what mean when you say "in case my dataadapter is null" you mean returns zero rows ?

Comment: yes exactly .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acb32th4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx here is a good explanation of how data adapter works

Comment: Ok I give Up. I will just clear the rows before every fill. I try to fill a data table with 12 rows with a MySQL table with 2 rows and the fill method didn't clear the data table but it just updated the first two rows and kept the rest. Oh well :(